# Change source of one index from pacmd list-source-outputs

Tags: command-line, 20.04, sound, pulseaudio

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. I was researching about the command pacmd and pactl but I did not find anything helpful. I want to know the specific command to change the source from one index in the pacmd list-source-outputs. In the screenshots [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjYOS.png) and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPcA8.png), you can see in yellow what I would like to change via one command.

It is possible to do the change in the GUI of pavucontrol or Volume Control, see [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNcYt.png).

I would like to know which respective command in the terminal is used.

Volume Control:

[image: screenshot of Volume Control]

Index before change:

[image: screenshot of index before change]

Index after change:

[image: screenshot of index after change]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I tried using strace but analyzing the output is too much work and I don't think it will help in finding out the command.